# .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting on C application

Tags: .net, c, runtime-error

Folks,

I have an issue with a legacy C application, it is multithreaded and consists of a mix old c code and a some c++ code. developed in VC6.0

The Application also uses COM Interop using .Net DLLs registered using regasm with the codebase and tlb switch.

I have the application running through the same test ona test automation PC.

I have Application Verifier running to check for Heap corruption but in this case its not reporting any.

The application crashes with the usual windows error dialog popping up and asking if you wish to send to Microsoft.

In the Microsoft Windows Application Event Log I see the following when my application crashes, the app that is reported to have crashed is the C application:

Any ideas how to trace the culprit here?

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1000
Date:       31/10/2013
Time:       10:21:20
User:       N/A
Computer:   **********
Description:
Faulting application ******.exe, version 0.0.0.0, stamp 526fe6e7, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 5.1.2600.2180, stamp 411096b4, debug? 0, fault address 0x00001010.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
Data:
0000: 41 00 70 00 70 00 6c 00   A.p.p.l.
0008: 69 00 63 00 61 00 74 00   i.c.a.t.
0010: 69 00 6f 00 6e 00 20 00   i.o.n. .
0018: 46 00 61 00 69 00 6c 00   F.a.i.l.
0020: 75 00 72 00 65 00 20 00   u.r.e. .
0028: 20 00 ** 00 ** 00 ** 00    .*.*.*.
0030: ** 00 ** 00 ** 00 ** 00   *.*.*.*.
0038: ** 00 ** 00 2e 00 65 00   *.*...e.
0040: 78 00 65 00 20 00 30 00   x.e. .0.
0048: 2e 00 30 00 2e 00 30 00   ..0...0.
0050: 2e 00 30 00 20 00 35 00   ..0. .5.
0058: 32 00 36 00 66 00 65 00   2.6.f.e.
0060: 36 00 65 00 37 00 20 00   6.e.7. .
0068: 69 00 6e 00 20 00 6e 00   i.n. .n.
0070: 74 00 64 00 6c 00 6c 00   t.d.l.l.
0078: 2e 00 64 00 6c 00 6c 00   ..d.l.l.
0080: 20 00 35 00 2e 00 31 00    .5...1.
0088: 2e 00 32 00 36 00 30 00   ..2.6.0.
0090: 30 00 2e 00 32 00 31 00   0...2.1.
0098: 38 00 30 00 20 00 34 00   8.0. .4.
00a0: 31 00 31 00 30 00 39 00   1.1.0.9.
00a8: 36 00 62 00 34 00 20 00   6.b.4. .
00b0: 66 00 44 00 65 00 62 00   f.D.e.b.
00b8: 75 00 67 00 20 00 30 00   u.g. .0.
00c0: 20 00 61 00 74 00 20 00    .a.t. .
00c8: 6f 00 66 00 66 00 73 00   o.f.f.s.
00d0: 65 00 74 00 20 00 30 00   e.t. .0.
00d8: 30 00 30 00 30 00 31 00   0.0.0.1.
00e0: 30 00 31 00 30 00 0d 00   0.1.0...
00e8: 0a 00                     ..
```

Comment: Hmm.. I think you need to narrow down exactly what you are doing in your code when it crashes, then try to pin down the problem to a small area of code. If you can do that, then post the code, we might be able to help better.

Comment: I cant narrow down the exact point in code because i don't think the C application is the problem, my main question is why do i see a .Net error in the event log for a C application?

Comment: Are in a position to debug the DotNet code?

Comment: No the DLL's are from 3rd parties

Comment: It doesn't feel like there's a lot for us to go on here. I think you need to work out which .NET function your application is calling when the crash occurs. That's the first stage. That should allow you to define your question a bit more precisely.

Comment: I am not calling any .Net method, all the .Net calls will not execute as they are not configured to do so, the only thing that would occur at startup of the c app is it would init the .Net dll and call its constructor